# How to link to Show page of parent object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an application with Users, Machines, and Tests.
Users have many Machines and Tests
Machines belong to Users
Tests belong to Machines

**While on the Test Show page, I want to add a link to go to that Test's parent Machine Show page. **

My TestsController reads:

```
  def show
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
...
end
```

My Test show page has the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Back to Machine', machine_path(@machine) %>
```

For some reason the link is sending the user to

```
 /machines/test_id
```

instead of

```
/machines/machine_id
```

I think I need something in the TestsController Show section like:

```
def show
@test = Test.find(params[:id])
@machine = Machine.find(params[:id])
...
end
```

but it must not be correct because I'm getting errors.

Comment: I suspect your @machine is not initialized, in case if show is not called before pressing link_to 'Back', you get error.

Comment: Not sure how show wouldn't be called before I press the link_to 'Back.... How would I resolve that?

Comment: in that case initialize the `@test` and `@machine` in index action also. make sure you pass id of test in params while calling index. but then u will have to initialize @machine as shown by Azolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
def show
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  @machine = @test.machine
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes! Azolo, you're a badass. Thanks.

In retrospect this question seems stupid. But I was definitely stuck.